# Issuing JWT token myself versus using IdentityServer4(OIDC) for Web API

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, jwt, identityserver4, openid-connect

https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/intro/support.html

I currently issue tokens myself in my web api with `JwtSecurityToken` and I use standard ASP.NET Core middleware calling `AddJwtBearer` to verify the tokens. It works fine.

What advantage will give me using OpenID Connect (through IdentityServer4) over the approach described above? How to answer myself question "Do I need OpenID Connect?"

From my basic understanding about OpenID Connect, it is used to allow third parties to access your API. But I make API for myself and not for third parties and I don't know why should I favor IdentityServer/OpenIddict over my simple approach.

I read that if I want Single sign-on I should use this, but JWTs itself aren't bound to any specific domain and I can use single sign-on with just pure JWTs(they're self-contained)

I understand it implements some kind of standard for issuing tokens. (protocol). It might be good if I ever wish to expose some API to third parties. But for internal APIs? Is it worth using it?

This is my current auth flow (from https://jonhilton.net/2017/10/11/secure-your-asp.net-core-2.0-api-part-1---issuing-a-jwt/)
[image]

What I really want to implement to secure my Web API:

- Login
- Logout (invalidate token?)
- No consent screen (want to have API only for myself), auth happens in the background in my native desktop, mobile, web app (no redirection)
- Remember me feature (refresh tokens?)

Could someone clear out the fuzzy picture of OIDC/OAuth2 for me? i.e. give me some disadvantages going my own way (implementing my own flow) and advantages of using OIDC in place of my own flow.

What will it save me from doing later on (on the client-side for example), and what will not. And most particularly, is it good to start every project using standard flows like OIDC? Will it somehow benefit me in the future?

Comment: And why do you use tokens in the first place? Mobile apps with cookie problems, multiple api endpoints which look at token for permission checks instead of database (for perfomance), something else?

Comment: Yeah performance, native apps, can be used across different domains easily. I think tokens are more often used for Web APIs nowadays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In any case you will implement OAuth2. Think of Oidc as an extension of OAuth2. The most important thing to keep in mind is *seperation of concerns*.

Forget Oidc, Identity Server 4 is all about authentication: "who is the user"? Consider Google login. When a user logs in for the first time, the application doesn't know the user, it only knows that Google does.

Authorization takes place on a different level and isn't really a concern of IdentityServer. For that you could take a look at [PolicyServer](https://leastprivilege.com/2018/01/17/announcing-policyserver/).

So you'll need to keep the user database seperated from the application database. This doesn't mean you need another database, just don't mix contexts. If you have a relation from the "business context" to e.g. the user table in the "Identity context" then you are going to have a problem eventually.

In your setup your web api is both the *resource* and the *identity provider*. This means that every new web api you create has to be implemented as both resource and identity provider. For maintainability you could create a seperate web api that acts as an identity provider, while the web api is a resource only. You can implement something like that as long as all apps can read the token.

The same counts for the front. Why should the front have anything to do with the user? All it needs to do is pass the token in order to get the user authorized. In case of IdentityServer, the app contacts it to verify the user and receives a token. It knows nothing about credentials. This is more secure. The client app can be compromised. The credentials can be intercepted.

Having single apps with a specific concern makes things more maintainable. And it is quite easy to add a new resource without having to code when you use IdentityServer. Just add the configuration. It also allows you to add other flows in the future that are not needed at this time. And as a side note, the consent screen is optional.

The bonus is that you can implement SSO, where in your setup that could be harder, if not impossible.

So you don't have to use IdentityServer, nor Oidc. Your setup may be just fine. But if you build something, keep seperation of concerns in mind.

Comment: If I use ASP.NET Core Identity to store user data, does it mean I should have a separate context for that in entity framework?

Comment: You have two types of information: Identity and Business. The identity provider has access to the identity model and the resource (web api) to the business model. If you spit these, you'll need seperate contexts. If you need to show the username in a report, you'll have to create a user table in the business context where you can store the information. It then becomes business information. This may seem redundant, but it is not. The information has a different meaning / purpose. You can use UserId (just the value, not as database relation) to link the current user to the business user.