# Database Setup for Identity Server with Web API and SPA

Tags: single-page-application, asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4

I was wondering how an app(created with the 3 pieces shown in diagram link below) should be setup in terms of database sharing/isolation. The Web API would have authorization requirements and the identity server obviously just does authentication.

- I feel like Diagram 1 would be optimal but I am not sure of the drawbacks that could be faced in the future from that kind of setup, or if it is even a proper way to use an identity server in terms of sharing a database with the application.
- The issue I am finding in Diagram 2 is that the App database does not have a reference to the identity users tables, so relational data would be weird or I would have to keep a synced user reference table.
- If the identity server database should be isolated from the application database, should the application database store the users full gamut of information and the identity server database just have a small reference to the users such as username/login and other authorization columns? And how would they be kept in-sync?

[image: Application Architecture]

Comment: Perhaps my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52079466/is-claims-based-authorization-appropriate-for-individual-resources/52100609#52100609) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49781664/issuing-jwt-token-myself-versus-using-identityserver4oidc-for-web-api/49790781#49790781) may be helpful.

Comment: yeah that would do it :)